# ASP.NET Core (2.1) Web API: Identity and external login provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been discovering a bit the ASP.NET Core for a few days and wanted to try implementing authentication via LinkedIn.
Most of the tutorials I found online used MVC and this is a seamless process, but I wanted to do a pure API.
I've got something working, but I am not sure this is secure (I've hit some issue that I 'fixed' in a way that may be insecure).

---

#### Context of the application:

- I am developing a Web API, with JWT Bearer token based authorization, which means I don't have any cookie based authentication
- A SPA (React app) will interact with the API
- I am trying to implement most of the external login logic on the server to ease the development of the SPA

When I configure Identity, I use `services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()` and not `AddIdentity<>` to avoid adding cookies authentication schemes, and then `service.AddAuthentication(...).AddJwtBearer(...)`.
I put in place a registration/login with email/password, returning JWT tokens and using them to secure the access to the API methods and this works well.
So far so good.

The issue I faced came when I `.AddLinkedIn()` (from the [aspnet-contrib providers](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers)).
I added the route `/login/external?provider=LinkedIn` whose(?) only role is to

```
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider)
{
    return Challenge(provider);
}
```

redirect the user to the provider login page. That's the first thing I made that I think could be a dirty/insecure fix, but it works: I am redirected on the LinkedIn login page and then on my callback page (in this case: `/login/linkedin?code=`).

That's where something I don't understand happen: the `AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn.LinkedInAuthenticationHandler` is called, probably based on the callback path, and validates everything. It also tries to sign in, but this does not work since I have not configured a SignIn scheme (JWT Bearer only allows Authenticate and Challenge schemes).
Worse, when I used `AddIdentity<>` on my first tries, I got a callback loop looking like that:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/login/external?provider=LinkedIn  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Route matched with {action = "ExternalLogin", controller = "Login"}. Executing action RestAPI.Controllers.LoginController.ExternalLogin (RestAPI)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method RestAPI.Controllers.LoginController.ExternalLogin (RestAPI) with arguments (LinkedIn) - Validation state: Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action method RestAPI.Controllers.LoginController.ExternalLogin (RestAPI), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult in 0.2266ms.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (LinkedIn).
info: AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn.LinkedInAuthenticationHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: LinkedIn was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action RestAPI.Controllers.LoginController.ExternalLogin (RestAPI) in 248.7148ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 805.406ms 302 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/login/linkedin?code=xxx&state=xxx  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
      AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed in.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 1142.4957ms 302 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/login/external?provider=LinkedIn  
...
...
...
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/login/external?provider=LinkedIn  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Route matched with {action = "ExternalLogin", controller = "Login"}. Executing action RestAPI.Controllers.LoginController.ExternalLogin (RestAPI)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method RestAPI.Controllers.LoginController.ExternalLogin (RestAPI) with arguments (LinkedIn) - Validation state: Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action method RestAPI.Controllers.LoginController.ExternalLogin (RestAPI), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult in 0.0104ms.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (LinkedIn).
info: AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn.LinkedInAuthenticationHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: LinkedIn was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action RestAPI.Controllers.LoginController.ExternalLogin (RestAPI) in 2.5893ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 4.3076ms 302 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/login/linkedin?code=xxx&state=xxx  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
      AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed in.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 716.1161ms 302 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/login/linkedin?code=xxx&state=xxx  
warn: AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn.LinkedInAuthenticationHandler[15]
      '.AspNetCore.Correlation.LinkedIn.OH3a8tiReVSVrkJ9eEUA0eA-W6UDfSJRoO7GyoLLNCo' cookie not found.
info: AspNet.Security.OAuth.LinkedIn.LinkedInAuthenticationHandler[4]
      Error from RemoteAuthentication: Correlation failed..
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login. ---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 245.3085ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
```

The `CookieAuthenticationHandler` redirects the user to the user the original URI, where he gets redirected by the challenge (I think, still not sure why though. I also tried to check if the user was authentication in the `ExternalLogin` action to avoid challenging the user when he goes on this page, but it doesn't seem to be the case).

To 'fix' both of these issues, I ended up disabling the SignIn phase in the AuthenticationHandler by requested a `SkipHandler` on the context when I receive a new ticket (which is done when the AuthenticationHandler validates that the authentication with LinkedIn was successful):

```
.AddLinkedIn(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = Configuration["authentication:linked-in:client-id"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["authentication:linked-in:client-secret"];
    options.CallbackPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/login/linkedin");
    options.Events.OnTicketReceived = context =>
    {
        context.HttpContext.User = context.Principal;
        context.SkipHandler();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

I also attach the `Principal` claim from the context to the `HttpContext.User` because I don't have access to the claims in the action of the `/login/linkedin` otherwise, and I need to have access to the user LinkedIn ID there.

The `/login/linkedin` action is then a matter of finding the user by login provider using the `UserManager.FindByLoginAsync` method, and if I don't find the user, creating it, to finally generating a JWT like I do for a standard(with password) user.
I finally redirect the user to the URI of the SPA (something like: `/external-login-callback#auth_token=XXX&refresh_token=XXX`), so that the SPA can store the token in the local-storage and use it to authenticate the subsequent requests.

A second issue related to this method is that I don't seem to have access to the token given by LinkedIn for the user (they don't seem to be stored anywhere, or maybe I don't know where to look), so I cannot create the `IdentityUserToken` for this external login provider (although this doesn't seem to be an issue).

---

So in the end, I do have something working, and I don't see any issue with it.
However, I am kind of a newbie in web API and I am really not sure this is a valid/safe method to do it.

---

My questions are:

1. First, can it be the job of the API to do the external authentication? Or should it exclusively be the role of the SPA to redirect the user to the correct URL?
   I have seen quite a lot of people saying that it is not the API that will request but that it should be the SPA.
2. Do I leak any sensitive information doing that?
   Is there a chance an attacker could fake a user request and get access to my application because of the way this is done?
3. How could I get the `access_token` related to the user from LinkedIn?
   What would be the use for this token, given that the `LinkedInAuthenticationHandler` already makes a request to the LinkedIn API to get the user id/email?
   Is it required to store it to validate that the user didn't remove my app from his permitted services in LinkedIn?

---

Hopefully this is clear and I'll be able to get some answers, but if not, don't hesitate to ask for precision.
If you had the courage to read everything (and even if you don't!), thank you!

Comment: I would not recommend having the API handle external authentication.  Have you looked into using an Identity Server such as [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/)?  This can handle your authentication flow (including external providers) and allows you to issue your own tokens instead of using third party tokens.

Comment: I've looked into IndentityServer4 yes, however I felt like it's overkill for a 'simple' API. I know that, once you have multiple services requiring authentication, it's worth it, but I didn't deem it necessary for my project. I'll still take a closer look on how to handle external authentication with it, it may be worth it in the end. What's the main reason behind not recommending the API to handle external auth?

Comment: Because it's an API, not a web app.  Your using LinkedIn external authentication which requires a browser based authentication flow.  API's don't usually return redirects and the assumption is the client may not be a browser.  If access to your SPA requires authentication then the web app serving the SPA can handle the authentication.  You can embed the access_token somewhere in the page so it can be used by your JavaScript client to access the API.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense actually! Thanks for the input, I'll see how to do it from the SPA then