# How to grant access to users externally authenticated and not registered in my WebApp using asp.net core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

> **Summary**

This is my first try with OAuth2 and External Login Mechanisms.

I'm creating a WebApp that will expose API features through a user-friendly UI.

In order to make API calls, I need to receive an access token from QBO that grants access to resources.

So, my WebApp has an external login option which I use to authenticate against QBO, and then authorize my app.

Everything works fine until...

[image: Error loading external login information.]

> **Services Configuration**

Based on a tutorial for GitHub authentication, I came up with this.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(o => {
            o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            o.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        })
            .AddOAuth("qbo", "qbo", o => {
                o.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-qbo");
                o.ClientId = Configuration["ecm.qbo.client-id"];
                o.ClientSecret = Configuration["ecm.qbo.client-secret"];
                o.SaveTokens = true;
                o.Scope.Add("openid");
                o.Scope.Add("profile");
                o.Scope.Add("email");
                o.Scope.Add("com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting");

                o.AuthorizationEndpoint = Configuration["ecm.qbo.authorization-endpoint"];
                o.TokenEndpoint = Configuration["ecm.qbo.token-endpoint"];
                o.UserInformationEndpoint = Configuration["ecm.qbo.user-info-endpoint"];

                o.Events.OnCreatingTicket = async context => {
                    var companyId = context.Request.Query["realmid"].FirstOrDefault() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("realmId");
                    var accessToken = context.AccessToken;
                    var refreshToken = context.RefreshToken;

                    Configuration["ecm.qbo.access-token"] = accessToken;
                    Configuration["ecm.qbo.refresh-token"] = refreshToken;
                    Configuration["ecm.qbo.realm-id"] = companyId;

                    context.Backchannel.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);
                    context.Backchannel.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    var response = await context.Backchannel.GetStringAsync(context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);

                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response);

                    var user = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
                    user.AddClaims(new Claim[] {
                        new Claim("access_token", accessToken),
                        new Claim("refresh_token", refreshToken),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, result["givenName"]),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, result["familyName"]),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, result["email"]),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, result["givenName"]+" "+result["familyName"])
                    });
                };
            });
```

This works. I can add my claims based on user information, the context.Principal.Identity indicates that it's authenticated.

For some reasons, it seems to try and redirect to `/Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl=%2F. Why is that?

> **Login page redirection**

Here, I don't get why I get the redirection and this confuses me a lot. So, I added the AccountController just to try and shut it up.

```
namespace ecm.backoffice.Controllers {
    [Authorize]
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class AccountController : Controller {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "/") {
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(string returnUrl = "/") {
            await Request.HttpContext.SignOutAsync("qbo");
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
       }
    }
}
```

And this creates more confusion than it solves, actually. I'm lost here...

> **Apply Migrations**

This Individual User Authentication WebApp seems to use Identity which looks like it creates a lot of behind the scene mechanisms. I first tried to register to my app, and had to "Apply Migrations", which I totally get, since the data model wasn't initialized.

So, I clicked the Apply Migrations button. I though I was okay with this...

> **Entity Framework Core**

I am aware that the app is using Entity Framework Core for its persistence mechanism, hence the registration process, etc. And to configure it, I needed to add these lines to the services configs.

```
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

It looks like it just won't work at all.

> **Thoughts**

At this point, I think that the message says it Entity Framework just can't load the user information from its underlying data store. I totally understand that, and I don't want to register this user. I just want to take for granted that if QBO authenticated the user, it's fine by me and I grant open bar access to the WebApp features, even if the user ain't registered.

How to tell that to my WebApp?

> **Related Q/A I read prior to ask**

[Prevent redirect to /Account/Login in asp.net core 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53925609/prevent-redirect-to-account-login-in-asp-net-core-2-2)
[ASP.NET Core (2.1) Web API: Identity and external login provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883634/asp-net-core-2-1-web-api-identity-and-external-login-provider)
[asp.net core 2.2 redirects to login after successful sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54354247/asp-net-core-2-2-redirects-to-login-after-successful-sign-in)
[External Login Authentication in Asp.net core 2.1](http://asp.net%20core%202.2%20redirects%20to%20login%20after%20successful%20sign%20in)

And many more...